# Saving User Data to Array inside Struct

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, struct, swiftui

I'd like to properly save inputted user data / variables inside an array which is inside a struct but unable to get it to work.

Currently, I have a few structs:

```
struct Household: Codable {
    let id  = UUID()
    var region: String
    var householdSize: Int = 1
    var receivingBenefits: [String]
    var energyCrisis: Bool
    var utilityProviders: [String]
    var residenceType: String
    var propertyTaxPastDue, homeNeedsRepairs, filedPreviousYearTaxReturn, heatingSystemNeedsRepairs: Bool
    var atRiskOfHomelessness: Bool
    var receivedMaximumBenefit: ReceivedMaximumBenefit
    var personDetails: [PersonDetail]
    var incomes: [Income]
    var assets: [Asset]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case region
        case householdSize = "household_size"
        case receivingBenefits = "receiving_benefits"
        case energyCrisis = "energy_crisis"
        case utilityProviders = "utility_providers"
        case residenceType = "residence_type"
        case propertyTaxPastDue = "property_tax_past_due"
        case homeNeedsRepairs = "home_needs_repairs"
        case filedPreviousYearTaxReturn = "filed_previous_year_tax_return"
        case heatingSystemNeedsRepairs = "heating_system_needs_repairs"
        case atRiskOfHomelessness = "at_risk_of_homelessness"
        case receivedMaximumBenefit = "received_maximum_benefit"
        case personDetails = "person_details"
        case incomes, assets
    }
}

struct PersonDetail: Codable, Identifiable {

    let id  = UUID()  // <-- here
    var age: Int = 18
    var maritalStatus: String = ""
    var minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod: Bool
    var workStatus: String = ""
    var pregnant: Bool
    var attendingSchool: Bool = false
    var disabled: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case age
        case maritalStatus = "marital_status"
        case minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod = "minimum_employment_over_extended_period"
        case workStatus = "work_status"
        case pregnant
        case attendingSchool = "attending_school"
        case disabled
    }
}

class Base: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var household: Household

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case household = "household"
    }
}
```

Now, I can easily bind a Textfield, toggle or Picker to anything under the Household struct for example below which I believe is easily connected via household in the Base() class..

```
HStack() {
   Image(systemName:"wrench.and.screwdriver.fill")
               .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
  Toggle(isOn: $eligBase.household.homeNeedsRepairs) {
           Text("Need Home Repairs?")
                   .font(.system(size: 15))
              }.tint(.blue)
          }
```

However, I'm unable to connect anything in the array`[PersonDetail], which I included the struct.

For example, If I wanted to connected a Toggle for the disabled variable in `PersonDetail', I get an error, here is my disabled toggle:

```
 Toggle(isOn: $eligBase.household.personDetails.disabled) {
              Text("Disabled")
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
......
}
```

I receive an error stating:

> Value of type 'Binding<[PersonDetail]>' has no dynamic member
> 'disabled' using key path from root type '[PersonDetail]'

Any ideas how I can connect Toggles, Textfield, Picker to a variable in an array which is in a struct?

Comment: (an aside, but if you used `decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase` you could lose all the CodingKeys boilerplate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `List` for your array of `PersonDetail`, such as in this example code:

EDIT:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var eligBase = Base()
    
var body: some View {
    List {
        let _ = print("\n---> \(eligBase.household.personDetails.count) \n")
        Section("About You") {
            ForEach($eligBase.household.personDetails) { $person in
                HStack {
                    Text("Age")
                    Spacer()
                    Picker("", selection: $person.age) {
                        ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) {
                            Text("\($0)")
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(.menu)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Marital Status")
                    Spacer()
                    Picker("", selection: $person.maritalStatus) {
                        ForEach(0...3, id: \.self) {
                            Text("\($0)")
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(.menu)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        eligBase.household = Household(region: "xyz", householdSize: 0, receivingBenefits: [], energyCrisis: false, utilityProviders: [], residenceType: "", propertyTaxPastDue: false, homeNeedsRepairs: false, filedPreviousYearTaxReturn: false, heatingSystemNeedsRepairs: false, atRiskOfHomelessness: false, receivedMaximumBenefit: ReceivedMaximumBenefit(cip: false), personDetails: [PersonDetail(age: 33, maritalStatus: "single", minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod: true, workStatus: "ok", pregnant: false, attendingSchool: false, disabled: false), PersonDetail(age: 44, maritalStatus: "maried", minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod: true, workStatus: "ok", pregnant: false, attendingSchool: false, disabled: true)], incomes: [], assets: [])
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why when this is implemented, the section disappears? image url: https://imgur.com/a/4Wlog5D.

Comment: Also, it asked me to put the SwiftUI in from of the List, SwiftUI.List { .  Without the swiftUI in the front it was giving me this error: Use of 'List' refers to instance method rather than generic struct 'List' in module 'SwiftUI'.

Comment: If the the section disappears, it's probably because there are no `personDetails` in the array. To check this add 
`let _ = print("---> \(eligBase.household.personDetails.count) ")` just after the `SwiftUI.List`.  If the result is zero, 
then the `ForEach` will not show anything. You are made to use `SwiftUI.List` because you have declared a `List` instance method somewhere in your code 
and this is clashing with the SwiftUI existing struct.  This is not good practice, I recommend you change your `List` 
to something else, e.g `myList`. PS:  edit your question and show your code as text.

Comment: You may also see no entries in the `List` due to the way you layout the elements with the `HStack` etc... Try something simple first, then add to it when working.

Comment: Not sure what I may be doing wrong if it works for you.  The content doesnt show and I'm assuming it's because there's nothing in the array as you mentioned.  I copied your whole code exactly.

Comment: updated my answer with added `.onAppear` to show it works when you have some data.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind the control to the whole array of PersonDetail, not an individual entry within the array.

For example, if you always wanted to use the first personDetail instance in the array:

```
Toggle(isOn: $eligBase.household.personDetails.first!.disabled) {
              Text("Disabled")
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
```

In a real solution you'd probably want to safely unwrap whatever PersonDetail instance you want in the array, and cleanly handle the array being empty (as the forced unwrap in my example would crash if the array was empty).

Comment: I understand, and yes I do get a fatal error with your example.  
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.  

Since the .disabled item is the 6th item in the array, why wouldn't this work? 
$eligBase.household.personDetails[6].disabled

Comment: If it's 6th in the array, it will be `.personDetails[5].disabled`. Remember arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: Getting an INDEX OUT OF RANGE error now.  Well, if I take out the content let id, there are 7 items, which .disabled is last [6]. @flanker and getting the out of range fatal error.

Comment: `.disabled` is a property on a single instance of PersonDetail. It is **not** the sixth or seventh or any item in the array.   An array will have zero or more elements, each of which will be a PersonDetail struct, and each of these (if there are any) will have all the properties in the struct.  You need to identify the element in the array you want, and then access the properties on that.